# Error backup PostgreSql DB's using PGAdmin in AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, pgadmin

I am getting this error when trying to backup the data bases in the PGAdmin of PostGreSql to my computer:

pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied to set role "xxx"
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SET ROLE xxx

I can read from the tables and view all of the tables

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the with owner permissions to create the backup. The error might be because of the username (you are entering) has only read permissions or if not then the username might not be given the privilege.
Login with the owner of the database and then create the backup. There won't be any error in backup.